# How to play undead Gebbites

Tags: pathfinder-1e, undead, golarion

Let us take the nation of Geb. People there let themselves get killed to convert to an undead creature for political reasons. Let us further say I want to play such a character.

How does this change my personality? How much do I know about my former life? Am I still the same person just undead? Am I automatically evil? Is there any source material on how this transformation retains or changes the original person's nature?

Comment: This is too broad - at the very least you need to tell us how you became undead and what kind of creature you are. There is a world of difference between being raised as a Skeleton or a Lich.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Geb was a region - now I feel like this question is missing a setting tag or something.

Comment: OK so this question is partially answerable but where it verges off into alignment speculation it falls under too subjective given our meta guidance on alignment questions. It's fine that the question is a little vague, the top rated answer does a good job of breaking down the different options, but we need to focus on the rules aspect (do I gain the evil alignment, fine, can I 'be evil to fight evil because ends justifies the means' not fine).

Comment: Here, I edited along those lines and reopened.  Roll back if that doesn't correctly express your question.

Comment: The new title is way better and more descriptive.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### That depends on the type of undead you become

The people of [Geb](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Geb) are from a varied type of undead, some are *zombie lords*, *ghouls*, others are *vampires*, there are *ghosts* (like Geb himself), liches ([Arazni](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Arazni)). It all depends on how they died/what killed them, and other conditions necessary for each type of undead.

Example, those killed while infected with a ghoul's disease will likely raise as ghouls (or ghast if they have 4+ HD). Those bitten by a *vampire* might turn into another vampire. Powerful spellcasters who safeguard their soul in a phylactery might return as a *lich* upon death.

> Anyone who dies on Gebbite soil is reanimated as a mindless undead creature to serve the state in eternal bondage. Those with sufficient clout or wealth generally circumvent this procedure, and willingly **transform themselves into an intelligent undead creature**, either through dark magics, or simply by letting themselves be killed by ghouls, vampires, or other creatures with the ability to create such progeny.

But there are also **zombie and skeleton laborers** all over the country. Those are clearly mindless and have no memories of their past life.

> Geb is now renowned as a land of the undead, and while **plantations filled with zombie labourers** may stick in the mind, there is much, much more to Geb.
>
> (...)
>
> With its ruler now an immortal ghost, and **much of the populace animated as skeletons and zombies**, the land of Geb became known as a land of undead, much to the dismay of neighbouring and not-so-neighbouring nations.

Keep in mind however, that not everybody in Geb is an undead, only the majority of the population due to the "enviromental curse" on the country. This is specially true about travellers and merchants from nearby countries.

Answer (score 1):

After the transformation, you are no longer the same as you were before. Simple things you used to do and worry about no longer matter: breathe, sleep, food, sexual reproduction. Time is no longer a constraint for you, you will remain as you are eternally. Things and people die around you while you remain. That one embarks on this path with the purest of intention doesn't mean they will remain that way. Very few manage to stay pure without turning to evil or madness.

Now back to your questions:

- How much you remember of your life? It depends on the type of undead you became
- Are you still the same person? No, you will change, but you would still have a core of "you" in there.
- Do you become automatically evil? No, but it is a very likely course
- A good person using evil means to fight evil... So the end justifies the means... Yep, you will turn to the dark side of things.

Embracing evil to do good rarely lead to good things in the end...

Comment: "Embracing evil to do good" is a topic on the Champions of Corruption Player Companion book, i suggest reading it for ideas on how to play evil PCs, even if they act like good guys.

Comment: Great idea. Hadn't thought about that one, but yes.